# jQuery Unwrap data from $.Get

Tags: jquery, get, parent

Having received data via a `$.get` method we now want to remove its parent DIV. Any attempt to do this applying `unwrap()` to the variable data is not working.

```
$.get('???', {list_posts_id: $(this).data('list_posts_id')}, function(data){
 elem.parent().append(data.unwrap());
}
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$.get('???', {
    list_posts_id: $(this).data('list_posts_id')
}, function (data) {
    elem.parent().append($(data).unwrap());
})
```

The `data` looks like a string, so create a jQuery object using it then call `unwrap()`

Comment: Hmm. That should do it but it hasn't. The unwrap function now isn't doing anything

Comment: @RobinKnight what is the content of `data`

Comment: It contains HMTL as a string. This did it $(data).find('.post') With post being the name of the inner elements I'm after.

Comment: @DanielLisik [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) can take a success callback as third parameter

Comment: @RobinKnight yes... the context of the problem and the structure of the markup is important to solve this kind of problems.... without knowing what kind of html you have and what elements you are looking for it is difficult to find  a solution